# Java Snake Game Works Correctly Just Once Per Eclipse Restart

Tags: java

I've made decent progress coding a snake game as a personal project and managed to get the movement all done, however the movement only works on the first run each time I start Eclipse and then after that when I run the program the snake will not move. I can technically run it twice using the run button and then the coverage run button for the second. After that they both stop being able to produce the snake's movement. This is 100% consistent every time. It also sometimes works one more time after I save a change.

Game Class

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private int[] snakexlength = new int[750];
    private int[] snakeylength = new int[750];

private boolean up = false;
private boolean down = false;
private boolean left = false;
private boolean right = false;

private int lengthofsnake = 3;

private int moves = 0;

private Timer timer;
private int delay = 100;



public Gameplay() {
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    timer.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    if(moves == 0) {
        snakexlength[2] = 50;
        snakexlength[1] = 60;
        snakexlength[0] = 70;
        snakeylength[2] = 70;
        snakeylength[1] = 70;
        snakeylength[0] = 70;
    }

    graphics.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 905, 700);

    for(int a = 0; a < lengthofsnake; a++) {
        //if(a==0 && (up || down || left || right))
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.fillRect(snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a], 5, 5);
    //  if(a!=0) {
        //  graphics.setColor(Color.magenta);
        //  graphics.fillRect(snakexlength[a], snakeylength[a], 5, 5);
        //}
    }

    graphics.dispose();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    timer.start();

    if(up){
        for(int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            snakexlength[r+1] = snakexlength[r];
        }

        for(int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
            if(r == 0)
                snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r] - 10;
            else
                snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r-1];

            if(snakeylength[r] < 0)
                snakeylength[r] = 700;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    if(down){
        for(int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            snakexlength[r+1] = snakexlength[r];
        }

        for(int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
            if(r == 0)
                snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r] + 10;
            else
                snakeylength[r] = snakeylength[r-1];

            if(snakeylength[r] > 700)
                snakeylength[r] = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    if(left){
        for(int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            snakeylength[r+1] = snakeylength[r];
        }

        for(int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
            if(r == 0)
                snakexlength[r] = snakexlength[r] - 10;
            else
                snakexlength[r] = snakexlength[r-1];

            if(snakexlength[r] < 0)
                snakexlength[r] = 905;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    if(right){
        for(int r = lengthofsnake - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            snakeylength[r+1] = snakeylength[r];
        }

        for(int r = lengthofsnake; r >= 0; r--) {
            if(r == 0)
                snakexlength[r] = snakexlength[r] + 10;
            else
                snakexlength[r] = snakexlength[r-1];

            if(snakexlength[r] > 905)
                snakexlength[r] = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        moves++;
        right = true;
        if(!left) {
            right = true;
        }
        else {
            left = true;
            right = false;
        }
        up = false;
        down = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        moves++;
        left = true;
        if(!right) {
            left = true;
        }
        else{
            right = true;
            left = false;
        }
        up = false;
        down = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        moves++;
        up = true;
        if(!down) {
            up = true;
        }
        else{
            down = true;
            up = false;
        }
        right = false;
        left = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        moves++;
        down = true;
        if(!up) {
            down = true;
        }
        else{
            up = true;
            down = false;
        }
        right = false;
        left = false;
    }


}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Main Class with JFrame

```
    package snake;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame Window = new JFrame();
        Gameplay game = new Gameplay();
        Window.setBounds(0, 0, 905, 700);
        Window.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Window.setVisible(true);
        Window.setResizable(false);
        Window.setTitle("Snake Game");
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.add(game);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try removing `timer.start();` from `actionPerformed`, it doesn't seem to make sense since the timer will also call this method.

Comment: Move `Window.add(game);` before `Window.setVisible(true);`

Comment: talex one worked for me

Comment: Yep that was it thank you talex. Does anyone know the technical reason for this happening?

Comment: If you make a window visible before you have added all its components, it won't always be entirely ready at display time, and you may encounter several of this kind of glitches.

Comment: That's good to know thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Move**

```
Window.add(game);
```

**before**

```
Window.setVisible(true);
```

**answer by `talex`**

If you make a window visible before you have added all its components, it won't always be entirely ready at display time, and you may encounter several of this kind of glitches.
 **explanation by `Arnaud`**